# React Native keyboard pushes up modal on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, modal-dialog

I have a very simple modal component with a `TextInput` inside and whenever I focus on the `TextInput` my whole View gets pushed up.

For smaller modals this is not a problem, however I have a few modals with bigger Height, where I have the `TextInput` at the very top, making my text dissapear above.

I am using expo.

Things I tried:

- Add `expo/android/softwareKeyboardLayoutMode : "pan"` to expo `app.json`
- Use `KeyboardAvoidingView`
- Use a 3rd party modal component `react-native-modal`

Code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, KeyboardAvoidingView, StatusBar, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

const TestModal = ({ visible, onClose }) => {

const window = Dimensions.get('window');
const WINDOW_HEIGHT = window.height;

  return (
    <Modal animationType="fade" visible={visible} onRequestClose={onClose} avoidKeyboard={true} style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'grey', width: 350, height: WINDOW_HEIGHT * 0.8, borderRadius: 10 }}>
        <Text>This is a modal</Text>

        <TextInput style={{ width: 100, height: 40, borderRadius: 15, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1 }} />
        <Button title="Close Modal" onPress={onClose} />
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default TestModal;
```

[image: Modal problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the `statusBarTranslucent={true}` prop to the modal, so the keyboard is not pushing up the view.

I had use cases where the TextInput was on the bottom part of the modal, so I had to use react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view with the prop `enableOnAndroid={true}`, so it enables on android. (By default it is false...)

```
    <Modal
      ...
      statusBarTranslucent={true} 
    >
<KeyboardAwareScrollView enableOnAndroid={true}>{children}</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
   </Modal>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have this on your modal

```
avoidKeyboard={true}
```

And this from the docs

```
avoidKeyboard   bool    Move the modal up if the keyboard is open
```

Try setting it to false.

Comment: I tried every possible option, nothing works :/

Comment: I found that adding position: "absolute" to the Modal style kind of fixes it. But the modal moves slightly.